# Plant tissue cultures without Phytohormones?

Tags: botany, cell-culture, growth-media

Is it possible to do tissue cultures without using phytohormones like BAP or NAA. So to just use for instance MS-Media.

Online, I just found that every plant is possible to culture with the right media and growth regulators. But I want to know if it is possible in theory to do tissue cultures without using hormones and if it is what are the disadvantages of that.